# How to discover the Telegram Bot / Channel associated with a webhook URL

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

During a recent audit, we discovered a webhook integration between Github an a Telegram.  The payload URL in Github looks like:

```
https://integrations.telegram.org/github/ghWebhook/<12 character identifier>
```

It's unclear how this was added, to investigate further we would like to know what users, bots and/or channel(s) are associated with this integration the Telegram side.  Is there a way to determine this?